cypress: Failed to load resource when the component is with image url
I'm new with cypress and encounter a issue when doing the component test
I have a component "Hero" which the props is as below
type HeroProps = {
  heading: string;
  description: string;
  image: {
    id: string;
    url: string;
    alt?: string;
  };
};

which the image is from a content management system.
and here's my test
describe('Hero tests', () => {

  const prop = {
    heading: 'Heading for heading test',
    description: 'Description for description test',
    image: {
      id: 'test id',
      url: 'a url from CMS',
      alt: 'test'
    }
  }

  it('validate heading', () => {
    cy.mount(<Hero {...prop} />);
    cy.getByDataID(selectors.heading)
      .should('have.text', 'Heading for heading test')
      .and('be.visible');
  });
});

the test will pass but when I check the result from UI, I saw that the image can not show and the console shows:
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/cms/xxxx/xxx.png 404 (Not Found)

did anyone know where I may do wrong? Thank you!

One way to handle this is to intercept the request and supply the image from fixtures.
That way seems easiest as you don't have to worry about where the image is coming from.
In the following test I use the naturalWidth property of the <img> element to assert that the image has actually loaded.
const prop = {
  heading: 'Heading for heading test',
  description: 'Description for description test',
  image: {
    id: 'test id',
    url: '../../assets/cms/cypress.png',
    alt: 'test'
  }
}

cy.intercept(/cms/, { fixture: 'cypress.png' }).as('loadImage')

cy.mount(<Hero {...prop} />)
cy.wait('@loadImage')

cy.get('img')
  .then($el => {
    const element = $el[0]
    const width = element.naturalWidth
    return width
  })
  .should('be.gt', 0)

// OR

cy.get('img')
  .its('0.naturalWidth')
  .should('be.gt', 0)



Without the intercept


Hi @Aladin Spaz.
I tried the intercept but still got the error
Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: loadImage. No request ever occurred.
as I understand in the doc https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-url,
the first param accepts the regExp.
my URL is localhost:80080/asset/cms/xxx/xxx.png
and the code is cy.intercept('/./asset/cms./', { fixture: 'xxx.png' }).as('loadImage')
do you know where I may be wrong?
also I wonder why the URL should from a CMS but actually it's from localhost?

Yes, that looks like the URL matcher '/.*\/asset\/cms.*/' is not matching the request URL.  You are using Minimatch string (since it's in quotes) which is always a pain for me, so I use Regex (which has no quotes) - see my example I just used /cms/ which should be sufficient. If you really want to add in the asset part I think the Regex would be /asset\/cms/.

That worked, thanks for your help!
Also find the way to fix my previous code
cy.intercept('GET', /./assets/cms/./, { fixture: 'xxx.png' }).as('loadImage')
this will also work!
